# Tried to create DB with Django by mistake

Tags: mysql, django, django-syncdb, my.cnf

So I read somewhere that Django doesn't create the DB in production on MySQL. It only created the tables and you have to create the DB in MySQL before you can do `syncdb`. However, I made the mistake of doing `syncdb` when the database with the name in my.cnf didn't exist. And now I'm locked out of mysql. I can't log into it using `mysql -u root -p`. It gives me error: `ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Just comment out the part specific to the database in which Django tried to create tables (in the file my.cnf). Then you should be able to log into MySQL.